# Grunt - no image library that works. All are silently failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm grunt beginner. But whenever I install any kind of grunt library to handle images it does not work.

grunt-webshot, webshot, getPixels, node-image, node, gm, node-pngjs, imagemagick, node-png, png, get-pixels

```
grunt.registerTask("getPixels", "your description", function() {
    var fs = require('fs') , gm = require('gm');
    gm('source/templates/t1/images/menu_item_bg.png').size(function (err, size) {

        grunt.log.writeln(size.width > size.height ? 'wider' : 'taller than you');
    });


});
```

Silently fails. No error, no nothing (I get: Done, without errors). Does not enter callback.
Same is with other libraries I used.

Only grunt modules can be used in grunt? Dont Think so, it seems i can use any library by using `require()` and it should work. It works ok with `require('path')`
Any way I can debug it? Make it return some kind of error or fix this problem?

Edit
I wrote a `makescreenshot.js` script which I call with node

```
var webshot = require('webshot');
// also tried commented varians:
//webshot('google.com', 'google.jpg', function(err) {
//webshot('http://google.com', 'google.jpg', function(err) {
webshot('http://google.com', 'google.jpg', {}, function(err) {
    console.log('console.log ERROR: ' + err);
});
```

It returns the following: `console.log ERROR: Error: PhantomJS exited with return value 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I figured it somehow. The problem seemed to be not properly installed Microsoft Visual Studio I reinstalled MSVS 2013 Express and it started taking screens normally.